# Nested scroll not working (HorizontalScrollView inside HorizontalScrollView)

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview, nestedscrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I want to take advantages of the new NestedScroll features added in API 21.
My layout is very simple:

HorizontalScrollView
    LinearLayout (Horizontal obviously)
        Regular view
        HorizontalScrollView
            TextView

By default, nestedScrollEnabled is false. So I enabled it in xml for the child (eg the inner HorizontalScrollView) I want to be scrolled in priority to the root HorizontalScrollView.
Therefore it doesn't do anything. Only the top scroll view is able to scroll, the inner one seems to not see any scrolling touch events at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.majeur.test.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/text" />

        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

It is the wau it should works, I don't understand ...
Thanks

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score -2):

Try using NestedScrollView with child LinearLayout with orientation horizontal.

> NestedScrollView is just like ScrollView, but it supports acting as
>   both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions
>   of Android. Nested scrolling is enabled by default.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

Comment: In API 21+ support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView should be exactly the same as a framework ScrollView. Anyway I'll try with support library. The nested scroll is very badly documented, I can't figure out if support NestedScrollView is a vertical ScrollView or if it determines itself in which axes it should be scrollable.